# non portable pointer conversion Warning

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char *p=malloc(100);
    clrscr();
    printf("enter your name\n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    printf("%s",p);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

when compiling this c program "non portable pointer conversion" warning is occuring..What is the reason for the warning?

Comment: What compiler are you compiling this with, and with what flags/options?

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>`, is the warning still on?

Comment: and on which line does the error occur ?

Comment: i am using turbo c++ compiler

Comment: on 5th line the warning is occuring

Comment: after adding #include<stdlib.h> no warning is occuring...Thank you..

Comment: The warning is solved..why it is occuring? please explain..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The warning is solved..why it is occuring? please explain..?

You were missing the prototype for `malloc`, so the compiler assumed a return type of `int`.

```
char *p=malloc(100);
```

Assigning an `int` to a `char*` gives the warning. Apparantly they are the same size in your compiler, but they aren't the same size everywhere.

When you added the prototype (in your case by including `stdlib`), the compiler is told that the return type of `malloc` is `void*`.
`void*` is a pointer type that can be assigned to any other pointer type without a cast.